# Activate Tp-bat-balance

Tags: power-management

I have a t400 with an ultrabay battery. How do I get [this to work](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Code/tp-bat-balance)? I want to balance the batteries discharge. I am coming from Windows so I don not know much about Linux. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The automatic formatting on the linked website tries to interprete the code of the perl script, thus breaking it and making it rather hard to understand. If you click on *View source* you can get the raw code.

Here is what the script from [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Code/tp-bat-balance) should look like. Please take note of the warnings therein.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Keep two ThinkPad batteries (system battery and UltraBay) at similar charge levels
# during discharge by switching back and forth. This reduces wear on the UltraBay
# battery, compared to the hardware's default strategy of fully draining the UltraBay
# battery before switching to the system battery.
# WARNING: This script is experimental and uses undocumented hardware features.
# WARNING: If this script crashes, your battery may be forced to keep draining until empty.
# Distributed under the terms of the GNU General Public License v2 or later.

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $thresh = 3; # difference between battery charge levels that justifies switching (hysteresis)

my $default_discharge = 0; # the battery that's discharged as first priority by the BIOS
my $smapi_dir = '/sys/devices/platform/smapi';

my $ac_connected;
my @bat_installed;
my @bat_remaining;
my @bat_state;
my @bat_power_avg;
my @bat_force_discharge;

$SIG{'INT'} = $SIG{'QUIT'} = $SIG{'TERM'} = sub { die("# Killed by SIG$_[0]\n"); };

sub read_chomp_file {
  my ($filename) = @_;
  my ($x) = read_file($filename) or die "Cannot read $filename\n";
  chomp($x);
  return $x;
}

# Read battery status from tp_smapi sysfs interface
sub read_status {
  $ac_connected = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/ac_connected");
  for my $b (0..1) {
    $bat_installed[$b] = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/installed");
    $bat_force_discharge[$b] = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/force_discharge");
    if ($bat_installed[$b]) {
      $bat_remaining[$b] = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/remaining_percent");
      $bat_state[$b] = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/state");
      $bat_power_avg[$b] = read_chomp_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/power_avg") / 1000.0;
    }
    else { $bat_state[$b] = 'none'; }  #This var needs to always have a value for print_bat to not break. This covers the case of starting the program without a battery in the bay/slot.
  }
}

# Print status to stdout (ASCII graphics)
sub print_status {
  print "   ";
  sub print_bat {
    my ($b) = @_;
    my ($ll,$lr,$rl,$rr) = $b ? ('-','>','<','-') : ('<','-','-','>');
    my $icon = sprintf("[%3s]", $bat_installed[$b] ? $bat_remaining[$b]."%" : "");
    my $arrow;
    my $state = $bat_state[$b];
    if ($state eq 'charging') {
      $arrow = sprintf("$ll--%4.1f--$lr", $bat_power_avg[$b]);
    } elsif ($state eq 'discharging') {
      $arrow = sprintf("$rl--%4.1f--$rr", -$bat_power_avg[$b]);
    } elsif ($state eq 'idle' || $state eq 'none') {  #Added none to cover case with no battery in slot when program was started.
      $arrow = "          ";
    } else {
      die "Unknown state $state for battery $b";
    }
    print($b ? "$arrow$icon" : "$icon$arrow");
  }
  print_bat(0);
  print($ac_connected ? ' {AC} ' : ' {  } ');
  print_bat(1);
  print("\n");
}

# Choose which battery to discharge
sub choose_discharge {
  sub set_force_discharge {
    my ($b,$on) = @_;
    return if $b!=$default_discharge; # the non-default battery will be discharged only when necessary anyway
    return if $bat_force_discharge[$b]==$on;
    write_file("$smapi_dir/BAT$b/force_discharge", ($on?'1':'0')) or die ("Cannot write to $smapi_dir/BAT$b/force_discharge: $!\n");
    print("# setting force_discharge on battery $b to $on\n");
    $bat_force_discharge[$b] = $on;
  }

  if ($ac_connected || !$bat_installed[0] || !$bat_installed[1]) {
    for $b (0..1) {
      set_force_discharge($b,0);
    }
  } else {
    if ($bat_remaining[0] > $bat_remaining[1] + $thresh) {
      set_force_discharge(0,1);
      set_force_discharge(1,0);
    } elsif ($bat_remaining[1] > $bat_remaining[0] + $thresh) {
      set_force_discharge(0,0);
      set_force_discharge(1,1);
    }
  }
}

while (1) {
  read_status;
  print_status;
  choose_discharge;
  sleep(5);
}

END {
  print("# Cleanup\n");
  write_file("$smapi_dir/BAT0/force_discharge", ('0'));
  write_file("$smapi_dir/BAT1/force_discharge", ('0'));
}
```

You have to save it in some file, for example `battery-balance.pl`. Then you need to make it executable. Best open a terminal and go to where you saved the file, then execute

```
chmod a+x battery-balance.pl
```

This makes the script executable for all users. But as this script tries to modify system files it will probably only run successfully with super user permissions. Therefore you have to call it with `sudo`:

```
sudo ./battery-balance.pl
```

Now it should show you which battery will be drained and update this every 5 seconds.

I would suggest testing it this way for quite some time before thinking about starting it in some automatic way.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I will start working on it today with your instructions and let you know how it.goes.

Comment: That's what the voting and acceptance buttons (to the top left of the question) are for. You can accept on answer for each of your questions. Starting with 15 reputation points you may vote up any question or answer, starting with 125 you may also vote down.

Comment: Okay, so I tried it out but im having some difficuly. At first it said no file found, so I changed directory, I think I was suppose to do that. Then I tried entering the commands and got this:                                                          kid@kid-ThinkPad-T400:~$ Can't locate File/Slurp.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./battery-balance.pl line 12.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./battery-balance.pl line 12.

Comment: That is Perl telling you that it is missing the libraries for `File::Slurp`. Try installing the package `libfile-slurp-perl`.

Comment: Awesome, looks like its working. Thanks so much for your help :D

Comment: kid@kid-ThinkPad-T400:~$ cd Downloads
kid@kid-ThinkPad-T400:~/Downloads$ chmod a+x battery-balance.pl
kid@kid-ThinkPad-T400:~/Downloads$ sudo ./battery-balance.pl
[sudo] password for kid: 
   [32%]           {  } <--13.1---[82%]
   [32%]           {  } <--13.1---[82%]
   [32%]           {  } <--13.8---[81%]
   [32%]           {  } <--15.4---[81%]
   [32%]           {  } <--16.0---[81%]
   [32%]           {  } <--15.4---[81%]
   [32%]           {  } <--16.1---[81%]
   
   that's what its looking like. I will start testing it only a daily basis and see how it works.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this a permanent thing?

Comment: There are several ways this can be done. Quick and dirty: Adding `nohup /PATH/TO/battery-balance.pl > /dev/null &` before `exit 0` should start the script at startup and discard all output to `/dev/null`. A better way would probably be to extend this script to start as a daemon and create an init script for it.